# Imagem panoramica em C# Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms

Estou fazendo um novo projeto usando C#  windows forms, e precisava abrir uma imagem panoramica e rotacionar ela apenas na horizontal. 
Procurei alguns exemplos na internet, mas não encontrei nenhum que seja claro.
Alguem tem algum exemplo que possa me ajudar.

Comment: Você vai precisar dar um pouco mais de informação, mostre um modelo de como você quer, em qual controle ela vai ficar e qual é o seu código.

Comment: Não escrevi código nenhum ainda, estou lendo e tentando entender como funciona para assim começar. O que preciso é colocar essa imagem panorâmica em um form e rotacionar ela apenas na horizontal. @KhaosDoctor

Comment: Acredito que o picturebox tenha uma propriedade para isto:
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750475(v=vs.110).aspx, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2163829/how-do-i-rotate-a-picture-in-c-sharp, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3b575a03(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Tente inserir uma `PictureBox` dentro dum `Panel` cuja propriedade `AutoScroll` seja **True**, e então modifique a propriedade `Height` da imagem dentro da `PictureBox` para ser a mesma do Panel.

Considere `pb` sua `PictureBox`, `p` o `Panel` que iremos usar, e `img` a Imagem de panorama:

```
//crie um handler no "p" para o evento "Load"
void p_Load(Object sender, EventArgs args) {
   // isso irá ativar a ScrollBar automática no painel
   p.AutoScroll = true;

   // adiciona o controle "pb" para dentro do painel
   p.Controls.Add(pb);

   // modifica a localização e dimensões da imagem
   pb.Location = new Point(0, 0);
   // define a imagem para o pb
   pb.Image = img;
   // auto ajusta a imagem
   pb.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
   // chama a variável "SystemInformation.HorizontalScrollBarWidth"
   // que é o tamanho horizontal da scroll bar
   pb.Size = new Point(img.Width, img.Height -  SystemInformation.HorizontalScrollBarWidth - 1);
   // atualiza a PictureBox
   pb.Refresh();
}
```

se quiser atualizar a imagem, só chamar o método `p_Load` novamente.